# Из longint(pchar('file.name')) приходит всего одна буква. Почему?

Tags: delphi

Разрабатываю программу, в ней реализовываю запись снимка с web-камеры в БД.
Пока на уровне разработки пытаюсь сохранить хотя бы в файл.
Воспользовался кодом:
`SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, longint(pchar('name.bmp')));`
Но почему-то сохраняет лишь первую букву для названия файла.
Как исправить данный недочёт?

Comment: Возможно - разница в Ansi/Unicode. Если приемное окно - Ansi, а Delphi - юникодная, то так и будет. Варианта два - либо создавать приемное окно через W-функции, если это возможно, либо явно привести строку к AnsiChar и потом - к PAnsiChar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всей видимости, приемное окно считает получаемую информацию `ANSI`-строкой, в которой на каждый символ приходится 1 байт. Если Delphi - юникодная, то тип `PChar` равен `PWideChar`, где каждый символ это два байта. Для английских символов старший байт будет 0. С учетом того, что окончание строки PChar ориентируется на символ `#0` - ANSI-окно вполне вправе посчитать старший байт первого символа (`#0`) за окончание строки.

Вариантов решения два:

1. Создавать приемное окно через W-функции (Unicode)
2. Явно преобразовать передаваемую строку в Ansi, т.е. `PAnsiChar(AnsiString('name.bmp'))`

Comment: Большое спасибо. Воспользовался более простым, вторым способом.

Answer (score 0):

pchar - это символьный тип, попробуйте использовать строковый тип.
Так-же могу предложить посмотреть решение проблемы в [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590328/saving-a-captured-image-without-using-clipboard-with-wm-cap-savedib-using-c) теме

Comment: `pchar - это символьный тип, попробуйте использовать строковый тип.` Поясните это свое утверждение (некорректное, кстати) и дополните, какой "строковый тип" вы подразумеваете в терминах WinAPI?

Comment: На msdn сказано что это указатель на символ, так что я исходил из этого. Если это не так, то прошу прощения за дезинформацию.

Comment: `PChar` - указатель на первый символ строки. Непосредственно по указателю содержится первый символ. Окончанием строки считается терминальный 0 (символ с кодом 0). А вот сколько байт займет этот терминальный нуль - зависит от того, PAnsiChar это или PWideChar.

Comment: Все ясно, буду знать.